# How to I dynamically rewrite the url and then reroute in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to retrofit multitenancy onto a large ASP.NET MVC application.  I want all routes that begin with `/client/{client}/{*path}` to really route to `{*more}`, but with some per-client setup behind the scenes (so that a specific database is being pointed to and stuff like that).

I have made an `IRouteHandler`, and it seems like it might actually work.  But there's a lot of MVC black boxes here I don't really understand, so I was wondering if any MVC experts could tell me if there's any issues with this approach, or what a better one might be?

```
public class ClientRoute : IRouteHandler
{
    ...

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) 
    {
        this.m_Path = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["path"];
        this.m_Client = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["client"];

        string virtualPath = "~/" + this.m_Path;
        requestContext.HttpContext.RewritePath(virtualPath);

        var route = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(requestContext.HttpContext);
        requestContext.RouteData.Values.Clear();
        requestContext.RouteData.Values.AddRange(route.Values);
        requestContext.RouteData.Route = route.Route;
        requestContext.RouteData.RouteHandler = route.RouteHandler;
        requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Clear();
        requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.AddRange(route.DataTokens);

        return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when user goes to `http://xxx/client/client1/home`, internally it goes to `http://xxx/home` ? Why? One alternative I can think of is using IIS Rewrite module

Comment: @LostInComputer, @ScottStafford:  That won't really work.  If `http://example.com/client/JoesMeats/Home` were rewritten to `http://example.com/Home` then any links on that page would have absolutely no idea what client they belonged to.

Comment: @Dan-o. you can rewrite the URL so that the client is either in the query string, server variable, etc. But, a bigger question is why should the URL be rewritten in the first place? Maybe i'm missing something

Comment: @LostInComputer: neither of you were talking about that.  I just figured that the mechanism for tying a request to a client would be significant - since the only reason I can think of to rewrite the url is for aesthetics.

Comment: I currently have a site where, for each client, we create a new web application in IIS, with it's own web.config, virtual directory mounted at /client/client1, /client/client2, etc.  I want to move to a single web app that is mounted at the root and services multiple clients.  I'm trying to trick MVC into not realizing I'm doing this, so I don't have to change every route in this (large) system.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: Attribute Routing doesn't work for your scenario? http://attributerouting.net/